# error: ora-01427 - "single row subquery returns more than one row"

Tags: ora-01427

guys! Could you guys help me with this query, I'm getting this error: ora-01427 - "single row subquery returns more than one row".

**Here's my code:**

```
SELECT (
   
        SELECT TO_CHAR(MAX(VW1.DATA_CONTRATO), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
        FROM VW_TEMPO_PROC_LICITATORIO VW1
        WHERE VW1.DATA_CONTRATO <
                            (
                            SELECT MIN(VW2.DATA_CONTRATO)
                            FROM VW_TEMPO_PROC_LICITATORIO VW2
                            WHERE VW2.IDENTIFICADOR =  VW1.IDENTIFICADOR
                            WHERE VW2.CENTRO_CUSTO <> 
                                                ( 
                                                SELECT VW3.CENTRO_CUSTO
                                                FROM VW_TEMPO_PROC_LICITATORIO VW3
                                                WHERE VW3.IDENTIFICADOR = VW2.IDENTIFICADOR
                                                AND VW3.DATA_CONTRATO = 
                                                                    ( 
                                                                    SELECT MIN(VW4.DATA_CONTRATO)
                                                                    FROM VW_TEMPO_PROC_LICITATORIO VW4
                                                                    WHERE VW4.IDENTIFICADOR = VW3.IDENTIFICADOR)))
        ) FROM DUAL;
```

I need my subquery to return just one line as a result.